# Pros and cons of various jQuery Modal Window plugins?

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I've been using Fancybox for modal pop-ups within my jQuery stuff for a little while.

It's nice. I like it. I do find the CSS a bit unwieldy, though.

I thought I should spend some time and really look at the options and try to decide to 'standardize' on one for my own work.

Have you chosen a standard modal implementation in your jQuery work? If so, which did you go with and why?

For a while there it looked like ThickBox was slowly becoming a defacto recommendation but has since been put out to pasture.

Has anyone found one option clearly leading the pack or are they all pretty much 6/half dozen when compared?

Comment: What I've been looking for is one that will rescale on small devices and add scroll bars when necessary.  I've asked the question myself at http://stackoverflow.com/q/7180146/798420

Answer (score 2):

I use [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)'s dialog, witch can be set to modal.
It's easy to use and customize, and it's stable. It's a lot of activity in the jQuery UI project, and I would be surprised if development stopped anytime soon.

[demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal)

Comment: thanks, fredrik. That's a good point. Using the default UI implementation seems like a smart move. I'll play with it some and see how it works out.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I find most modal popups pretty much the same to use- there's pretty much one approach to use (high z-index `<div>` possibly laid on top of an `<iframe>`) and in fact, if you can't find one that you like and can style the way you want, then it's pretty easy to write your own.

Comment: Thanks, Russ. Writing our own is on the options list!

Answer (score 1):

We've had a lot of success with the [ColorBox plugin](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/).